# KEGG Annotation

Tags: r, bioinformatics, genome

I have a set of genes (Amino acid sequences). I want to find the Kegg based functional annotations or KO ids. Is there any KEGG database available for download? I want to use blast with that database. Additionally, I was looking for R package that can help me in this regard.

Hope so I have clarified my query. Thanks for your response in advance.

Comment: KEGG database is not free anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KEGG database required subscription:

https://www.bioinformatics.jp/en/keggftp.html

Price list:

https://www.bioinformatics.jp/docs/subscription_schedule.pdf

If you remain interested here is listing of data available:

https://www.kegg.jp/kegg/download/

FASTA sequences are here:

https://www.kegg.jp/kegg/download/Readme/README.fasta